# How to import third-party JS files after pageload to get good page score

Tags: performance, shopify, pagespeed, zendesk, hotjar

I am using Zendesk, Hotjar, and Klaviyo on a Shopify website and getting a very bad page score in Pagespeed Insights.

**With these third-party widgets:** Speed score for mobile is 15 and desktop is 60

**Without these third-party widgets:** Speed score for mobile is 55 and desktop is 87

Here is a screenshot from page speed insights:

[image]

## Tried following points with no luck:

- loading these scripts with async attribute
- load these scripts with window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded' and also tried to add some delay

Is there any method to load these scripts without affecting the page speed?

Comment: Try to load delay the same. it is not 100% full-proof, but able to get some good Google PSI scores.

Comment: Tried the same. How did you do it at your end? @Onkar

Comment: I think these are added into`{{content_for_header}}`?

Comment: Yes! I tried to remove them from `{{content_for_header}}` and load them separately but no changes in pagespeed.

Comment: You need to load them on demand like a scroll, mouse move, or a certain amount of time.